# How can I exclude certain values when using "random" in Python?

Tags: python, random, python-3.3

I'm a new programming student and have just learned about 'random' in Python 3.3. I've decided to try and build some code for a text based Yahtzee game for practice and pure fun.

I have a general idea as for how most of the mechanics will work, but am hitting this little speed bump at the moment.

Example:

Round 1 yields
Die 1: 3
Die 2: 5
Die 3: 1
Die 4: 3
Die 5: 3

Each 'Die' is `random.randint (1,6)` [Six-sided die] 
As you can see, I have 3 of a kind and I would obviously want to keep that and use my next two turns to build upon it if I can. 
What I'm wondering is if there's a way to keep Dice 1, 4 and 5, but 'shake' the other two (Assign them a new random number between 1-6).

I was thinking user input to trigger switches, but am still a bit confused as to how that will pan out.

Comment: You probably need to think about this problem quite differently.

Comment: As far as assigning my variables, or are you talking about the overall approach?

Comment: For an approach I may suggest you to create a function for die roll and append its return value to a list. Get input from user to which rolls will be replaced, according to that input, re-assign that list item. Finally you can do whatever you want with that list. Count item occurance etc..

Comment: Going to try it out and I'll get back to you. Thanks for the input!

Comment: If you do accept the user input (asking which die to keep), you can use *args.  *args lets you pass an arbitrary number of arguments (e.g. the user can keep just the first two dice, the last 3 dice)